# News Detail Page with dynamic structure - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a news detail page such that it supports 1-5 number of images, twitter tweets, facebook videos/images/posts, bulleted lists. The problem is that I am getting this data as HTML and won't be having a definite structure of this detail view. It may have a combination of any of the above, or can be as simple as plain text with 1 image. How can this be handled?

In addition, this detail page will consist of multiple records (multiple of the above records in 1 page), which will be handled through tableview.

How can this be done?

I was going to put webview into tableviewcell and loadHtmlString into it but looking for a better approach instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: use webview if you are getting html.

Comment: @R.Mohan Any better approach by scraping HTML and avoiding webview?

Comment: Try MD String. and MarkDown Parser to parse it.

Comment: @sharadchauhan please give some links if possible

Comment: https://github.com/keitaoouchi/MarkdownView this is a library I am using for my article page.

Comment: Even if we parse this, how will we make the cell to show it?

Comment: why you need a cell ? just take one view and pass MD String it will render the view. Check the github project and try to run it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160159/discussion-between-dia-and-sharad-chauhan).